# dlib is not installing in pythonanywhere virtualenv

Tags: django, python-2.7, dlib, pythonanywhere

I am trying to recognize faces in an image using "face_recognition" library,to use it we have to install dlib but when installing dlib in pythonanywhere virtualenv console it is throwing some errors 
below is the error I got during installation of dlib

```
(env) 16:09 ~/dlib (master)$ python setup.py install --yes 
USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --no DLIB_USE_CUDA                                                                     
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating dlib.egg-info
writing dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
error: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

Try installing from this cmd command, assuming that you have already added pip in path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's some strange problem with the current version of `dlib` that's stopping it from installing on PythonAnywhere.   Version 19.3.1 seems to work:

```
pip2.7 install --user dlib==19.3.1
```