# Problem with dlib Installation on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib, pythonanywhere

I wanted to install dlib on pythonanywhere in order to use the `face_recognition` library. But my installation took a lot of time and errored in the end. Couldn't find much information about how to install `dlib` there.
Maybe somebody here can help?

P.S. I managed to install `dlib` and use `face_recognition` on my laptop, it was not so difficult. But I am new to pythonanywhere, maybe there is something I do not understand right.

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pi
p-install-4DFAdK/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4DFAdK/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__f
ile__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/p
ip-record-Xo9wmw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should try to install it on a Python 3 environment?

Comment: @norok2 I tried (created virtual environment with python 3.8 in it), but got the same mistake with failing building wheel for Dlib.

Comment: I was able to install dlib in py 3.8 venv, although it was cpu intensive. On pypi they list support for Python 2.6-3.6, but maybe it's not updated. There's also this answer which indicates that older version of dlib might be more stable on PA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285316/9536161

Answer (score 0):

face_recognition package requires dlib and it is very problematic package. I prefer deepface package because it is keras based and more lightweight. Besides, if you can install dlib, deepface wraps dlib as well.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID", "ArcFace", "Dlib"]
result = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
```